# What's the application of multi subfiles in a single tiff file?

Tags: image-processing, tiff

I am confused by the feature of [multiple/multi-page images (subfiles) per TIFF file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_Image_File_Format#Multiple_subfiles) .Can anyone give some application of this feature?

It seems if a tiff file contains more than one images, the normal image-viewer can't view the tiff file. So what's the difference between the multi-page feature and just archieving the multi image files into a single file by using command like 'tar'.

Comment: not much diff, but if the spec had called for using tar, then multipage tiffs wouldn't be tiffs anymore, they'd be a tar file that happens to contain multiple tiffs

Comment: *the normal image-viewer can't view the tiff file* - well, such an image viewer simply does not support tiff files in general, merely a small subset of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One application that I have come across is in diagnostic systems that produce multiple views that may need to be shown one on top of each other selectively.  A single TIFF is loaded and then the user is presented with the ability to display/hide layers that may include information at different wavelengths, from different sensors and possibly layers of annotation markings.